# Iterating over a set of lists, one list at a time

Tags: python, list

I have the code below. Can "The Loop" be simplified so that I do not have to repeat the statements?

```
topic1 = ["abc", "def"]
topic2 = ["ghi", "jkl", "mno"]
topic3 = ["pqr"]

outfile = open('topics_nodes.csv', 'w')
outfile.write("Node;Topic\n")

# The Loop
for i in topic1:
    print i
    outfile2.write(i +";1\n")
for i in topic2:
    print i
    outfile2.write(i +";2\n")
for i in topic1:
    print i
    outfile2.write(i +";3\n")
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just do:

```
for index, topic_list in enumerate([topic1, topic2, topic3], 1):
    for i in topic_list:
        print i
        outfile2.write('{:d};{:d}\n'.format(i, index))
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer, but I believe it is more readable to use `format` like this: `outfile2.write('{:d};{:d}\n'.format(i, index))`.

Comment: or just loop with a concatenated list as `for index, lst in enumerate(topic1+topic2+topic3, 1):` to save an inner loop. Also try to avoid using `list` as a variable name

Comment: @Anzel oops that happens when I don't have my trusty IDE to point out this kind of no-nos to me. I will change that immediately. But i need the index of the outer loop to know which index to write into the file.

Comment: yes if you need the index from outer loop that totally makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Nessuno is sufficient in this case, but in general you may also want to check the [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer) class, which provides an unified interface for writing CSV files:

```
import csv

with open('topics_nodes.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(('Node', 'Topic'))

    for topic, nodes in enumerate([topic1, topic2, topic3], 1):
        for node in nodes:
            print node
            writer.writerow((node, topic))
```

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` the lists, then loop over their items.

```
>>> for i, li in enumerate((topic1, topic2, topic3), 1):
...     for x in li:
...         print(x, i)
... 
abc 1
def 1
ghi 2
jkl 2
mno 2
pqr 3
```

Comment: Missing the semicolor `;`

Comment: It's also missing the file I/O on purpose, because that's not really part of the question.